# php json foreach string value

Tags: php, json, html

I have a JSON file which contains some movie data:

```
[{
    "title": "Bad Company",
    "desc": "------------------------",
    "rating": "6.0",
    "image": "Psycho-Ex-Girlfriend-Twisted-2018.png",
    "url": "master.m3u8",
    "category": "اكشن"
}, {
    "title": "The Pinch",
    "desc": "------------------------",
    "rating": "6.1",
    "image": "Psycho-Ex-Girlfriend-Twisted-2018.png",
    "url": "master.m3u8",
    "category": "اكشن , جريمه"
}, {
    "title": "Catskill Park",
    "desc": "------------------------",
    "rating": "6.2",
    "image": "Psycho-Ex-Girlfriend-Twisted-2018.png",
    "url": "master.m3u8",
    "category": "خيال علمي , رعب"
}, {
    "title": "Klippers",
    "desc": "------------------------",
    "rating": "5.3",
    "image": "Psycho-Ex-Girlfriend-Twisted-2018.png",
    "url": "master.m3u8",
    "category": "اثاره , اكشن"
}, {
    "title": "Psycho",
    "desc": "------------------------",
    "rating": "5.6",
    "image": "Psycho-Ex-Girlfriend-Twisted-2018.png",
    "url": "master.m3u8",
    "category": "اثاره , دراما"
}]
```

I need to add all titles to a drop down menu, and when a user selects an item from the menu show the desc, image and category.
by php

Can anyone help me please?

my traying code

```
$url = 'http://localhost/ar.json';
$xx = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

$data = json_decode($xx, true);
$search='title';

foreach($data['meta_data'] as $d){
    if($d['key']==$search){
        $found=$d['value'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $found?$found:"$search not found";
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself to achieve this requirement? If so please show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes i try for foreach but didnt work im jsut beginer thanks you for answer :)

Comment: Ok so show us that code. It will give us a better idea of what you are actually doing and in what language

Comment: $url = 'http://localhost/ar.json';
$xx = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

$data = json_decode($xx, true);
$search='title';

foreach($data['meta_data'] as $d){
    if($d['key']==$search){
        $found=$d['value'];
        break;
    }
}
echo $found?$found:"$search not found";

Comment: Add that to your Question, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53593819/edit) link under the question. Nobody can read code in a comment

Comment: @RiggsFolly i do

Comment: Sorry that was wrong

Comment: @RiggsFolly can you help me to do that pleas

Comment: It would be useful to see where the `meta_data` part actually appears in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure, which you do not fully how us, is correct.

Use the key and value method of a foreach like this

```
$url = 'http://localhost/ar.json';
$xx = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

$data = json_decode($xx, true);
$search='title';

$found = false;

foreach($data['meta_data'] as $key => $val){
    if($key == $search){
        $found = $val;
        break;
    }
}
echo $found ? $found : "$search not found";
```

Comment: thanks  meta_data is not important please how can i echo desc and other in same opject titek

Comment: Every Occurance in that array has a `title` key? Maybe you should you be looking for a specific value like `Bad Company` rather than a key of `title` ??